# Calls are ignoring method decorator

Tags: python, twisted, python-decorators

I'm using [PyDispatcher](http://pydispatcher.sourceforge.net/) along with [Wrapt](https://wrapt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)'s `@synchronized` decorator. When PyDispatcher calls one of my handler methods, it's ignoring the function decorator.

I have created a test case for this. Running the following code runs both threads simultaneously, but the expected behaviour is that the `@synchronized` decorator should prevent the second thread from entering the `_method_b` method until `_method_a` has finished:

```
from wrapt.decorators import synchronized
import time
from twisted.internet import reactor, threads
from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks
from pydispatch import dispatcher

class TestSync(object):

    def __init__(self):
        dispatcher.connect(self._method_a, signal="A")
        dispatcher.connect(self._method_b, signal="B")

    @synchronized
    def _method_a(self):
        print "Before Sleep A"
        time.sleep(2)
        print "After Sleep A"

    @synchronized
    def _method_b(self):
        print "Before Sleep B"
        time.sleep(2)
        print "After Sleep B"

    def method_a(self):
        self._method_a()

    def method_b(self):
        self._method_b()

    def test(self):
        reactor.callInThread(dispatcher.send, signal="A")
        reactor.callInThread(dispatcher.send, signal="B")

ts = TestSync()
reactor.callLater(0, ts.test)
reactor.run()
```

If, however, instead of calling the methods from Pydispatch, I call them from another method, the `@synchronized` decorator does work as expected. This can be tested by using `method_a` and `method_b` methods which in turn call the decorated methods:

```
def __init__(self):
    dispatcher.connect(self.method_a, signal="A")
    dispatcher.connect(self.method_b, signal="B")
```

Is this expected behavior? How can I tell Pydispatch to not overlook the decorator?

Comment: I'm not familiar, but does the `@synchronized` apply to stuff *within* the function, or across functions? From an outsider's perspective, if I had two methods that each required a synchronized body, I wouldn't necessarily want/expect the methods themselves to be performed synchronized, if that makes sense. Again, not familiar with this decorator or `PyDispatch`, so I apologize if this is a nonsense comment.

Comment: By default it uses a RLock held on the object instance, so in this case it applies across methods, but the lock itself is stored as a instance attribute. That works, except, it seems, when called by PyDispatcher.

Comment: FWIW, the problem likely lies in the way that PyDispatcher appears to do some horrid things when attempting to call the callback function. The suspect code can be found in ``pydispatch.robustapply.function()``. No idea what they are attempting to do, but looks to circumvent the normal way is expected that a Python instance method is called, by bypassing the Python descriptor protocol and grabbing ``im_func`` or ``__func__`` directly, thus resulting in the ``synchronized`` decorator not working as intended as binding is defeated. So fault appears to lie with PyDispatcher package.

Comment: I had inspected `robustapply` and noticed the strange robustness, but couldn't dare to attempt a fix myself as I don't quite grasp why methods are called that way. Thanks for your insight.